# "to whom it may offend" vs. "to whom I may offend"

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, writing-style, politeness

In my opening speech, is it right if I say

> I apologize to whom **it** may offend"

or

> "I apologize to whom **I** may offend"

Comment: How badly do you want to offend them?

Comment: Apologize to everyone or no one.

Comment: Note that some people may be offended by your assumption that they will be offended.

Comment: Your speech may offend, thereby you offend. Both sentences are correct and will work. I'm editing the question for a bit of clarity.

Comment: Writing advice is probably OT on ELU, but the tag exists, so why not!

Comment: 'I apologise **if** I offend anyone.'

Comment: "Who(m)ever it may offend would be better, since it means "anyone who(m)".

Answer (score 1):

Some of us might quibble with word choice: 'apologize' would arguably not apply in cases where you plan to proceed with the offense. That said, clearly people regularly do so. Many also apologize for something they think "may" happen if the recipient of the apology is predisposed to taking offense. As such, the word "may" has a whiff of victim blaming.

I would choose to say something like the following if I were in your position:

> I'm aware what I'm about to say offends some people. My intent is not to offend.

However, if you insist on the word choice, the following sentence is one option that avoids the grammar tangle and removes some of the weird sensibility snafus of the choices you proffered:

> I apologize to those of you I offend.

Comment: Thank you very very much for advising me. This help me a lot. I appreciate it.